# Titanium Lazy loading only when image view is visible

Tags: ios, titanium, lazy-loading

I have 10 image views stacked on one another. (for loop)

9 of them are set to visible = false.

1 of them is set to visible = true.

I was wondering if there is a way to only load the image when the imageview visibility is set to true. i.e. after an image view is removed off the stack.

The trouble I am having is that it is loading all the images at the same time in the stack, slowing everything down.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < peopleJson.users.length; i++) {

            //create containers to store every child object

            containers[i] = Titanium.UI.createView({
                id : 'container',
                visible : false,
                width : '100%',
                zIndex : '0',

            });


            imageSwipeView[i] = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
                image : peopleJson.users[i].pictures[0],
                visible : true,
                containerObj : containers[i],
                containerObjPrev : containers[temp],
                pictures : peopleJson.users[i].pictures,
                indImageView : indImageView[i],
                basket : LabelBasket[temp],
                top : 0,
                zIndex : 2,
                width : '100%',
                defaultImage : 'images/plainbg.png',
                height : 510,

            });

    containers[i].add(imageSwipeView[i]);

    win.add(containers[i]);

    if (i == (peopleJson.users.length - 1)) {

        //show last container  when for loop is executed

        containers[i].visible = true;
        $.view_indicator.visible = false;


    }

[..]
```

This code snippet basically says stack up the containers ontop of one another, once loop has executed show last container.

Later on I have an onclick event for each image view, if clicked, it removes the container at the top of the stack and makes the one underneath visible.

What I am trying to do , is only LOAD up the imageView remote images when the container becomes visible.  Right now, it will try and load the images visible or not visible.

Comment: Post some code showing what you have and where exactly is your issue.

Comment: check amended post, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting path to image to different property:

```
imageSwipeView[i] = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
    _image : peopleJson.users[i].pictures[0],
    ...
})
```

and when you are setting up `visible = true` update `image` property:

```
containers[i].visible = true;
if (!imageSwipeView[i].image) {
    imageSwipeView[i].image = imageSwipeView[i]._image;
}

$.view_indicator.visible = false;
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this. Shouldn't lazy loading mean it loads it up on demand? i.e. what you described , without me having to worry about this

Comment: That worked perfectly. Just tried it. Not sure why it wasn't lazy loading by default.

Comment: Images are loading as soon as you add them to view.